# python3.9.2 asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError with aysncio.sleep

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, coroutine

A simple producer-consumer program. The code always throws `asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError` in the 3rd iteration every time. The reason seems to be that consumer was not get `await`, than `asyncio.sleep` got canceled and thus threw out the `asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError`. But the weirdest thing is who canceled the `asyncio.sleep` always in the 3rd iteration?

```
import sys
import time
import asyncio
from queue import Queue

num = 11
pipe = asyncio.Queue() 

async def producer(pipe):
    for i in range(num):
        # await asyncio.sleep(0) 
        await pipe.put(i)
    await pipe.put("")

async def consumer(pipe):
    while True:
        item = await pipe.get()
        print(item)
        if item == '':
            break        
        try:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
        except asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError as e:
            print(type(e),item)
            continue

async def main():
    q = asyncio.Queue()
    p = asyncio.create_task(producer(q))
    c = asyncio.create_task(consumer(q)) # exception not be raised until done

    await asyncio.gather(*[p])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

```
$ python test.py 
0
1
2
3
<class 'asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError'> 3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

The source code of `asyncio.sleep`.

```
async def sleep(delay, result=None, *, loop=None):
    """Coroutine that completes after a given time (in seconds)."""
    if delay <= 0:
        await __sleep0()
        return result

    if loop is None:
        loop = events.get_running_loop()
    else:
        warnings.warn("The loop argument is deprecated since Python 3.8, "
                      "and scheduled for removal in Python 3.10.",
                      DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)

    future = loop.create_future()
    h = loop.call_later(delay,
                        futures._set_result_unless_cancelled,
                        future, result)
    try:
        return await future
    finally:
        h.cancel()
```

Answer (score 0):

The event loop of `asyncio.run` only

> [runs *the passed* coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run)

before attempting to clean up all other outstanding tasks and coroutines.

Thus, the passed in coroutine should directly or indirectly `await` *all* tasks that are expected to finish before the loop shuts down.

---

Since `p`, `asyncio.gather(*[p])`, and thus `main` finish almost instantly, the event loop attempts to cancel the remaining task `c` early. That this coincides with processing the element 3 is incidental due to the number of suspensions happening until that point.

In order for `main` to wait for all tasks to complete, `await` or `gather` them all:

```py
async def main():
    q = asyncio.Queue()
    p = asyncio.create_task(producer(q))
    c = asyncio.create_task(consumer(q))
    await asyncio.gather(p, c)
```

Comment: @しんらてんせい Because ``asyncio.Queue.get`` does not suspend when there are items in the queue (meaning it cannot be receive cancellations) and you catch and ignore ``asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError`` on `asyncio.sleep(0)`.

Comment: Still two problems. Why the following consumer 4, 5, 6... not get canceled and when removes `await asyncio.sleep(0)` everything goes right.

Comment: @しんらてんせい Didn't I just answer that? ``asyncio.sleep(0)`` is the only thing in your coroutine that actually suspends and thus a) receives cancellations and b) delays the coroutine until the loop closes. If you remove it, of course a and b no longer apply.

Comment: Tried some modification to figure it out but still not get verified. What you mean is that  
 `gather` ends the `put` and thus `closes` the loop and this operation coincides with the third `sleep`, so it gets cancelled. Does the subsequent `get` and `sleep` run in the new loop by the queue?

Comment: @しんらてんせい There is only one loop. The loop *tries* to cancel ``c``, but since ``c`` rejects this the loop continues.

Comment: and the `<class 'asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError'>` still be raised?